# How to run ionic default sidemenu on browser

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework, ionic-native

I'm working on an Ionic application but I'm new to the Ionic framework.
I created a simple default side menu module using cmd run as `> ionic serve sidemenu`, but the page is not shown in the browser.

How should I make it run on the browser?

Can anyone point me in the right direction?
What am I missing here and what are the basic requirements I need to install?
I'm getting this on cmd:

[image]

Comment: What do you see, when you hit `http://localhost:8100` in your browser?

Comment: @DavidR site can't reached local refuse to connect.

Comment: @DavidR Few days ago when i run as `ionic serve sidemenu` at that time immediately page open on browser.but now its not coming i'm using  chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to create a *side menu* project you should do: `$ ionic start myApp sidemenu`.

An then to run it:

```
$ cd myApp
$ ionic serve
```

Hope it helps.